# Which C++ IDE supports a quick TDD work flow and the Google or Boost Test framework?

Tags: c++, ide, tdd

As of now, here's what I do(I use Visual Studio):

1. Create a Test Project
2. Add some tests
3. Add code. Compile and Run
4. When a test fails, Write code to make it pass
5. Repeat the previous 3 steps until I have the code I want.
6. Create a Main Project that uses the tested code.
7. Use the tested code in a feature/bug fix.
8. Somewhere down the line, there is an issue that requires tested code to be changed.
9. I need to now go to the test project and repeat steps 2 to 5.
10. Then get back to the main project and compile and run to verify the feature/bug fix.

What I would like to eliminate is the need for two different projects and reduce the time I have to wait between builds and the context switching required. In essence, I want to tighten the test-code-test loop.

Let's say there is an IDE where the tests are part of the main project itself.
Let's also say that the IDE could recognize test passes and fails.
Finally, lets say that compiling and running tests happens in the background and that I only have to deal with an error when code doesn't build or a test fails.

My workflow now only involves one project:

1. Create a Project
2. Add some tests to the project
3. Add code. Save.
4. When a test fails, Write code to make it pass
5. Repeat steps 2 to 5 until I have the code I want.
6. Add in logic that uses the tested code to implement a feature or bug fix.
7. If tested code needs to be changed, go back to step 2.

Comment: What do you currently do to approximate this?

Comment: I don't know about the "every time I save" part. I don't think that's useful, as it can be a huge waste of time. But for the rest, using Make should be enough.

Comment: Yes, that IDE is called Emacs!

Comment: @VladLazarenko: So you mean there is a way to configure emacs to detect the output of a test framework?

Comment: To the people who voted to close, I have re-phrased my question.

Comment: It seems to me that your two workflows are actually identical. #6 in the second workflow is 6 and 7 in the first workflow, and #7 is 8-10.

Comment: The difference between the two is that the second one has much less context switching and no manual triggering of builds.

Comment: @carleeto: So you have a "run tests" button that also triggers a rebuild. I would argue that building on every save is an extremely bad idea; I frequently save things that won't build (are not valid programs); that is not a problem.

Comment: (It should also be noted that building a project saves all open files in every IDE of which I am aware)

Comment: Yes, but the short cut for save (Ctrl-S) is almost instinctive. Therefore, even though build and run is one shortcut key and it does save, in practice you end up using Ctrl-S and F5 most of the time, which is an additional step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilation of C++ code is usually too time consuming to do it every time you save except for trivial projects. That said, [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) has an option to save changes before building. So instead of the save command triggering build you can have the build command triggering save which are conceptually different, but have the same effect. To reduce build times for subsequent builds you can use something like [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/).

As for running tests, you can do this in Eclipse by adding a target which runs unit tests which can also be triggered by the build. And you can have the tests and the code in one project of course.

Comment: Thanks. ccache looks interesting. I'm currently using Incredibuild (http://www.incredibuild.com/) on production code and compilation is fast enough (25 mins on a single quad core machine without it, 2 mins with it). I will look into using Eclipse.

Comment: Visual studio also saves on build (at least 2012 AFAIK); in fact I can't name a modern IDE that doesn't do this.

Comment: @CongXu That's true. However Visual C++ compiler is rather slow and doesn't have a reliable ccache equivalent.